# Can wifi admin view video downloaded from personal Outlook cloud onto personal laptop?

Tags: wifi, cloud-storage, microsoft, outlook

Can company wifi admin view a video I downloaded to a personal computer from my outside microsoft outlook account accessed through Chrome? I have a personal university Microsoft account https, which I accessed through a work wifi. Can my work wifi view the video? My company did not install anything on my personal computer.

Comment: Is the video a file attachment?

Comment: If the video viewed as external content from your Outlook email it could be possible. While Outlook through a web portal is accessed via **https**://login.live.com, if the video was from accessed via **HTTP**, so no encryption, then the network administrator could view the video either by intercepting content or visiting the URL themselves. However, if the video is an email attachment then it will be downloaded via HTTPS, so then the administrator will not see the content. -- In Chrome under your Downloads tab you can see the URL for the video downloaded to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks. Video was email attachment downloaded from: https://outlook.office.com/................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you downloaded it via https connection and you did actually check that the https connection was valid and if there was no device management installing a company root certificate then it is unlikely that the network admin of the company can inspect sniffed traffic.

They will however see which addresses your https connections have been made to and how many data was transferred.